# showing image from Amazon S3 bucket only with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-s3

Hypothesis: I have thousands of images into different folders in an amazon S3 bucket. I'd like to make them accessibile to unlogged users as slideshow, but I don't want to deal with db and server poor performance (in case of too many users at the same time) , so I'd like to use only javascript.

The problem is that I should however deliver to the client the file list, since I can't use XMLHttpRequest to fetch and parse the xml file that Amazon provides when you try to browse a bucket because (I expect) the browsing page should be located on my webserver.
I think I should write some server-side code to create,after every upload/modification, an updated filelist to share with users, but I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Can anybody suggest me the best way to proceed?
Happy New Year!

Comment: Do you control the file and folder names? If so, you could have your script probe how many images there are (i.e. check if 012/99.jpg exists etc) to avoid having a list of files.

Comment: it was my first choice (yes, I can choose the file name I prefer), and I still love it very much, but I'd like to show always the last modified files first AND I can't load all files data since they are too many and it would be slow. I though to choose consecutive numbers as filenames, but it would be difficult to handle in case of modification/erase of a file (last modified should always be the first in the slideshow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible answer, tell me what do you think about:
Amazon provides ListBucket operation http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPListBucket.html

I can choose how many results to get at once using max-keys and marker (for pagination) parameters (example: http://download.terracotta.org/?max-keys=5).
I will obtain a xml file (as smallas I want) that I can parse locally with js in a "list.html" file, for example.
I could then include this list.html file (that should print just the definition of an array of images) in a iframe included in my slideshow.html file on my webserver.

Too dirty?

Comment: I don't see a way to order the results with that SOAP API call. So it still doesn't seem to satisfy your need.

Comment: From my test, it seems that the xml is ordered by last modification, even if I didn't found a clear indication about that.

Comment: If that's the case then I'd say this is your best bet as much as I dislike SOAP.

Comment: Eventually I will use the REST API GET to create list.html file, however, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Amazon S3 JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/p/s3js/wiki/APIDocumentation) has a method, bucket.list() that will list the contents of a bucket.

Comment: It could be THE solution, but I'd like to get an ordered list with newest (and last modified)files first and it should not deliver the entire list, since it could be very large. I have to think how to choose the filename to make it possible through the "prefix" parameter